# Keep getting IndexOutOfBounds exception when trying to merge arraylist

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing a school assignment (so still a noob) but cannot seem to figure out why i keep getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.  any help is appreciation.  It's most likely some stupid mistake but i've gotten very good at not noticing those.  It's supposed to separate slice objects in to 3 ArrayLists, scramble those lists, then put them back in the correct order based on color.

```
public void scramble()
{
    ArrayList<Slice> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Slice> red = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Slice> black = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Slice> blue = new ArrayList<>();
    int blackListCount = 0;
    int redListCount = 0;
    int blueListCount = 0;
    for (Slice s : slices) {
        if (s.getColor().equals("red")) {
            red.add(s);
        } else if (s.getColor().equals("black")) {
            black.add(s);
        } else if (s.getColor().equals("blue")) {
            blue.add(s);
        }
    }
    blueScram(blue);
    blackScram(black);
    redScram(red);
    for (int i = 0; i < slices.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            temp.add(i, black.get(blackListCount));
            blackListCount++;
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            temp.add(i, blue.get(blueListCount));
            blueListCount++;
        }
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            temp.add(i, red.get(redListCount));
            redListCount++;
        }

    }
    slices.clear();
    slices = temp;
}

private void blueScram(ArrayList<Slice> blue) {
    for (int i = 0; i < blue.size(); i++) {
        switchSlice(blue, i, (int) (Math.random() * (blue.size())));
    }
}
private void redScram(ArrayList<Slice> red) {
    for (int i = 0; i < red.size(); i++) {
        switchSlice(red, i, (int) (Math.random() * (red.size())));
    }
}
private void blackScram(ArrayList<Slice> black) {
    for (int i = 0; i < black.size(); i++) {
        switchSlice(black, i, (int) (Math.random() * (black.size())));
    }
}

private void switchSlice(ArrayList<Slice> list, int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
    try {
        Slice temp = list.get(firstIndex);
        list.set(firstIndex, list.get(lastIndex));
        list.set(lastIndex, temp);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("IndexOutBounds while trying to randomize/switch elements of a slice list");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the initial (given) slice creation / sorting code

```
private static int[] getStandardPrizes()
{
    int[] arr = new int[20];
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (i%5 == 0)
            arr[i] = i*1000;
        else if (i%2 == 1)
            arr[i] = i*100;
        else
            arr[i] = i*200;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I get errors at if(i % 5 == 0) and the other if statements within the scope of the surrounding for loop

Comment: How large are each of `black`, `blue`, and red before attempting to mix them back into `temp`? (and I suppose also how large is `slices`? - but I expect it to be the sum of those three)

Comment: slices has 20 objects, 8 in blue, 4 in black and 8 in red

Comment: There's your problem. You attempt to enter into the conditional sections for the blue and red 10 times each. But there are only 8 elements in them. Did you intend to use `else if` like in your `getStandardPrizes()` shown there? Note that the change will then still be dependent on your data being exactly like that, it won't work for any general distribution of `black`,`blue`,`red`.

Comment: Actually `i < slices.size() - 1` implies maybe one of them is only entered 9 times. (or would be if the program weren't crashing). I assume that you want `i < slices.size()` to get account for _all_ of the slices and not omit one. But maybe you don't. I can't divine that.